# Fun with combinatorics and 80 business customers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In business with 80 workers, 7 of them are angry. If the business leader visits and picks 12 randomly, what is the probability of picking 12 where exactly 1 is angry?

(7/80)*(73/79)*(72/78)*(71/77)*(70/76)*(69/75)*(68/74)*(67/73)*(66/72)*(65/71)*(64/70)*(63/69)*12=0.4134584151106464

What is the probability more than 2 are angry?

My idea is to calculate the probability of 2,3,4,5,6, and 7 angry people just like did in the previous example and then add them altogether.

In the previous example I can seat the one person 12 times. In all the different 12 spots, and then times by 12. The problem I have now is, how many times can I seat 2 people in 12 spots? If I use the combinatorics formula I will get a negative factorial.

There must be a much easier way than this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one easier way to do it, which even lets you directly use the result from the first part as part of your calculations: "at least $2$" and "at most $1$" are complementary events, which means that the probability of one of them happening is equal to one minus the probability of the other happening, or written with more symbols:
$$
P(\text{at least }2)=1-P(\text{at most }1)
$$ And "at most $1$" takes a lot fewer steps to calculate (although technically, it's done in exactly the way you planned to calculate "at least $2$").

Comment: I am going to be honest with you - At the moment I don't understand the difference between exactly one, and at most one, at least mathematically. I am very tired.

Comment: @DavidLund Exactly one means exactly one. At most one means one or fewer, as in one or zero. So if you're going to calculate the probability of at most one, you need to calculate the probability of exactly one (which is what you've already done in the previous part) and the probability of exactly zero (which is easy), and add them together. It's a lot less work than calculating the probability for $2,3,4,5,6$ and $7$, and then adding them together, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Thanks. I just read upon what at most one means, and they said 0 as well.  Just like you now. I didn't think of 0. But I am very tired, as the time is 12:30 AM, I have been doing probability for 5-6 hours. Yes, I definitely agree. I think I can do it now, but still I am a little confused if I were to use the other method, how to seat 2 people in 12 seats. I might get it tomorrow though, but feel free to answer it if you want to. :P

Answer (score 3):

The denominators of the fractions stay constant. The total multiplication across the denominators is all the ways to pick 12 people from 80, where the order is retained:
$$ 80\cdot 79\cdot 78\cdot 77\cdot 76\cdot 75\cdot 74\cdot 73\cdot 72\cdot 71\cdot 70\cdot 69 = \frac{80!}{68!}
$$

We say that order is unimportant, so $\frac{80!}{68!\,12!} = {80 \choose 12}$ options

Then the numerators are the combination of the choices from the angry $(k)$ and non-angry $(12-k)$ groups, which are ${7 \choose k}$ and  ${73 \choose 12-k}$, so overall the probability is $$\frac{{7 \choose k}{73 \choose 12-k}}{80 \choose 12}$$
and checking this against your result for $k=1$ we have 
$$\frac{{7 \choose 1}{73 \choose 11}}{80 \choose 12} = \frac{68!\,12!}{80!}\frac{7!}{1!\,6!}\frac{73!}{ 62!\,11!} = \frac{12\cdot 7\cdot 68\cdot 67\cdot 66\cdot 65\cdot 64\cdot 63}{80\cdot 79\cdot 78\cdot 77\cdot 76\cdot 75\cdot 74} \approx 0.413458415
$$

The easiest of the possible calculations is where none of the chosen employees are angry $(k=0)$, which is 
$$\frac{{7 \choose 0}{73 \choose 12}}{80 \choose 12} = \frac{68!\,12!}{80!}\cdot 1 \cdot\frac{73!}{ 61!\,12!} = \frac{68\cdot 67\cdot 66\cdot 65\cdot 64\cdot 63\cdot 62}{80\cdot 79\cdot 78\cdot 77\cdot 76\cdot 75\cdot 74} \approx 0.305171687$$

Then all other cases can be worked similarly.

---

You talk about getting a negative factorial when finding the combination of how to choose $2$ seats from $12$, but that is just ${12 \choose 2}= \frac {12!}{10!\,2!} = \frac{12\cdot 11}{2} = 66$ so I don't know how you arrived at a negative factorial.

Comment: I have only been doing any kind of probability for 3 days so I always ask myself how many N people can sit at K spots. I have this formula that says n!/(n-k)!/k!. So if I have 6 people at 2 spots, it's going to be 6*5/2. So I just told myself 2 people at 12 spots. Following my formula and normal thought method that would be 2*1/(2-12)!/12!. I see that you have written it the other way around - 2 seats from 12. Anyway, I should just go to sleep now. I won't understand any probability right now anyway :P But thanks for the answer

Comment: I appreciate it, I will try to understand tomorrow.